# Powershell Rest call for etag

Tags: .net, rest, powershell

I am trying to get the etag number for a file by making a rest call. I need to be able to store the etag number to a text file. Since i need this work on PowerShell v2.0 I cannot use the `Invoke-WebRequest` method as it is not supported.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri
$response | select  @{n='ETag';e={ $_.Headers.ETag }}
```

I am trying to use the dot net method -

```
$response = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$etag = $response.DownloadString($URI)
```

However I am getting junk output. An example of the output when I run `$etag` -

```
PK    ÁMÕHÖnÖ™ª  ?    SelfDiscovery.ps1í]{sÇ‘ï¿¯ê¾ÃfÉD€+ñCË¡)*VE¹
Ú¼*ÓÅPBø )ó~õ»ôc3³;»X€ A-§P ÅÅlwO?~Ý=3ýßÿÃg@úp
Ç°çøÂ%þìâ5ú¤#ÀŒá?á?øMwìÁ{¼šâ¿RgDð_§øJà:H…®_âßü”èñ>úý;~N£ˆ[¯¥þ•àH¢)
òtrò•3¤©[xíU†³ð Z]¼—FwPÂ¾CŸZ9ºH{ÄŸž3âØÃßtE¸ßJCÒöñÕã7qv5ò¯’D#ä8à‘–ËÖÐÿ{
È’é'ßãß)sã¿ˆï¥÷¹¯]C|÷'s½d]Ùñ$±Ðë9<í¼ÏXo]¶Þ9¼3¥;š¬'EÞòU²œ¯Û##I2b=¨ÝÖXWøi
ÌÎ˜ôSôYßà»ÛðÒÈ°›8CÒâä÷O¼ÒHqOás8DY†(=Ñëà¿{ì‹'8¦  /YV±Ñ¶ÜöàçØGžOñ“-ØÅÏ
O²Wø×ðóu–hïNà_,×>ë—fÜÌHõ(T‡?ç5ØÀ÷!ê3Ëcÿ¾Rü×.Ïù©Y¿»Hï€yßLø¿4úî°íò2Ð
˜Ä¼Êµ–ˆî¿ñüù5ò:á»H»#ÃkÈÔ$^5V¬7$²ñü3Gß ¡]èNñˆ-ô®1ÇçqBhÐ<O9ÂFï(š«Ã0µ†áEöq
Qãx¡\rô•ïwl¯¼ëbá<]ÚÊ¯Çÿ­ùCNÊEH‘¥yPˆÝ-ƒùÕd•(žMÆpU•G§HGø:å¹Ÿ!Å'ð|_àÕ6^=Æ
```

Has anyone seen this before? I do not know what I am doing wrong, I have used this method before to make an API call.

Update - Thanks to Toni comment I can get the file downloaded

```
$response = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$etag = $response.DownloadFile($URI,$file)
```

But how do I get the etag? I am trying to achieve comparing the downloaded etag with the call etag. If there is a different, to download and extract.

Comment: The `PK` at the beginning suggests a compressed (zip) output. You need to decompress it. That won't be possible from a string, so use `DownloadData` or `DownloadFile` instead. Here is a list of helpful "magic markers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @TToni Thank you, I needed to be able to download the file so that helped in getting that resolved with a little help from - [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/00bd2230-ec02-4a91-940c-3ad252220a08/using-powershell-to-download-multiple-video-from-a-website?forum=winserverpowershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The etag is stored in HTTP headers, and what you're doing with the `WebClient.DownloadString` method is downloading the file and storing it in the `$etag` variable. Instead, try using a WebResponse object to access the response headers:

```
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri)
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$etag = $response.Headers["ETag"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That works perfectly. Powershell 2.0 makes it that little more difficult to research.